# Print timestamp in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to measure the time for each of build item in make file, i just try below, why does it not work?

```
mytest:
    $(info 'Now time is $(date --iso=seconds)')
```

The date is not printed, just printed

```
'Now time is '
```

. What can be wrong?

`make --version
GNU Make 3.81`

Comment: Found the comments can not embed code, i would ask another question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no `make` function named `date`.  If you want to invoke a shell command, the syntax is `$(shell date)`.

Using `$(info)` in a recipe is not particularly elegant; the function doesn't produce anything which is useful to pass to a shell.  You are probably looking simply for

```
mytest:
    date +"Now time is +%FT%T%z"
```

(Could not find `--iso=seconds` documented properly; grabbed the defintion from this blog: http://nixscripts.blogspot.com/2010/07/hidden-arguments-easter-egg-or-what.html)

... or perhaps somewhat less efficiently

```
mytest:
    printf 'Now time is %s\n' "$$(date --iso=seconds)"
```

where the double dollar sign escapes the dollar sign from Make so that you pass through a command substitution to the shell.

Just to point out the obvious, it is unfortunate that Make uses a syntax which is so similar to the shell's command substitution syntax.  Inside Make, you use `$(shell command)` or `$$(command)` to pass `command` to the shell.  The former makes sense in pure Make snippets (variable definitions in the `Makefile` proper, etc); the latter is only available in recipes.

Comment: There's also `!=` for assigning a value returned by a shell command.

Comment: @user657267 Thanks, I was not familiar with that.  Documentation e.g. at https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_0021_003d but in my quick experiment, it doesn't seem to work in `make` 3.81 on OSX; on Linux, with `make` 4.0, it does work for me.

Comment: Yeah it was added in 4.0.

Comment: For getting seconds from date --iso-seconds does not work for me on Debian, I use date +%s

Comment: @huesforalice That would give you the time in seconds, not in the ISO format produced by `--iso=seconds`. The first answer here shows how to get that with standard `date`, i.e. with the format string `+%FT%T%z`