# Get Timestamp in mk file

Tags: makefile, android-make

I could like to append a timestamp to the build property value in Android.mk file.Is there a way to get the current timestamp (format "YYMMDD") in a Android make file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print timestamp in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722572/print-timestamp-in-makefile)

Comment: Can you accept or close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is something specific with an Android make file, but the following works in GNUmake:

```
DATE := $(shell date --utc +%Y%m%d)

$(info Current UTC date is $(DATE))
```